how to use RBAC on azure?
I'm a complete beginner, but I need to figure out how do use rbac on azure sql to grant access specifically to certain tables on the db (for now, with just standard reader privileges). How should I do that?
Also, I'm really sorry if anything is super obvious...I'm just trying my best here.

Cross-site dupe: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/226881/azure-sql-database-grant-select-on-certain-tables, although I’m sure there’s one here as well

In a nutshell, rather than you grant access to individual users, you make users part of a group and then, grant the permissions to the group.
This Microsoft Learn link contains the steps you are looking for: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/secure-database-tutorial?view=azuresql
